べきもの in this sentence
そして心が動かないと言った彼の、これが本来の甘さなのだ。
――本来の……例えば恋愛相手、恋人。そんな役割を持つ誰か。そんな存在が受け取るべきもの。
Context: The character "彼" asked the narration/main character a kiss. So the narrator narrates this
"そして心が動かないと言った彼の、これが本来の甘さなのだ。"
The fact he said his heart won't move, this was a by nature sweetness (of him)
Then the narration adds

――本来の……例えば恋愛相手、恋人。そんな役割を持つ誰か。そんな存在が受け取るべきもの。

By nature... for example a romantic partner, a lover. Someone holding that role
Then I'm stumbled on the very last part
"そんな存在が受け取るべきもの。"
What is もの here?  "甘さ"?

To be clear, the question is what もの refers to? Why wouldn't it be... そんな存在 ? XがYもの（だ） seems like a pretty clear pattern to me.

Yes, as far as I can comprehend from information given, もの refers to 甘さ.
Or instead, as Karl Knechtel suggested in their comment, you can complete the sentence as

（彼の甘さは、）そんな存在が受け取るべきもの（だ）。

